# javascript value is true while it should be false?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I just started a little sideproject to learn more Javascript and in particular the canvas. I want to create a easy drawing app but I stuck at the moment.

Currently I've managed to get the drawing to work (needs finetuning but I just started) so now I want to place a mousedown and mouseup event into my code.

So this is what I did:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 10;
var drag = false;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight; //grootte van de canvas

var putPoint = function(e){
    if(drag = true){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        context.fill();
        console.log(drag);
    }
}

var engage = function(){
    drag = true;
}

var disengage = function(){
    drag = false;
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
```

I've put a variable "drag" into to check whenever the condition is true or false. By default I made it false. When the mouse down event is triggered function engage has to do its job and make the variable drag = true.

When the variable is true it should activate the putPoint function to draw the dots on it.

But the problem is. When I start the code It's true by default and not false. I just can't seem to find the problem here because to me it looks like everything is like it should be.

Hope you guys can help me and see what I've been doing wrong here.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tbmluijten/bTV9v/

Thanks!

Comment: `if( drag = true)` assigns `true` to `drag` and then checks to see if it's truthy (which it always is. Use `if( drag == true)`, `if( drag === true)` or just `if( drag)`

Comment: Ye it al makes sence now :D Thanks alot!

Comment: it was just a typo, please delete your post.

Answer (score 1):

You're not only testing, you're assigning then testing.

Change

```
if(drag = true){
```

to

```
if(drag == true){
```

or better

```
if (drag) {
```

In reference to the last example, [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) is a great article on the concept of `truthy/falsey` values.

Comment: Ah that was the problem indeed. If I look at it now it's pretty obvious. Thanks for the help and the article! :-D

Comment: @GameAlchemist It's not appropriate to ask a user to delete their answer. If you believe the answer is incorrect, downvote it. If you believe it doesn't address the question, then flag it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : So i'm the one not being appropriate, not the one posting a fish-for-point useless reply, nor the O.P. who does not delete a oops-i-made-a-typo post ? If you're ok with the level of garbage in S.O., great : i'm not.

Comment: @GameAlchemist "a fish-for-point useless reply" ? Don't you even know what a Community Wiki answer is ? By the way, when OP needs an explanation and an article, it's *not* a typo, even if it's a simple problem (which is why I made my answer CW).